# My suffix has only one, My whole is no one

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix is case closed.
- My suffix has only one.
- My infix is not closed.
- My whole is no one.

Answer (score 10):

> My prefix is case closed.

> Z, the last letter, case closed.

> My suffix has only one.

> O for *only* and for *one* (the first letter of each of those words).

> My infix is not closed.

> An ER, emergency room, should always be open to customers.

> My whole is no one.

> ZERO is not one.

Answer (score 2):

> ALONE

> My prefix is case closed.

> A, the first letter, case closed.

> My suffix has only one.

> ONE is literally only "one".

> My infix is not closed.

> When you don't close the lights they are ON.

> My whole is no one.

> ALONE means no one else with you.